# this.setState not working on componentWillMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the state to be dependent on server data. I thought of using componentWillMount:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState( async ({getPublicTodosLength}, props) => {
      const result =  await this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination();
      console.log("result = ", result) // returns the length but not assigned on this.state.getPublicTodosLength
      return { getPublicTodosLength: result+getPublicTodosLength }
    });
  }

  getPublicTodosLengthForPagination = async () => { // get publicTodos length since we cannot get it declared on createPaginationContainer
        const getPublicTodosLengthQueryText = `
          query TodoListHomeQuery {# filename+Query
            viewer {
              publicTodos {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`
    const getPublicTodosLengthQuery = { text: getPublicTodosLengthQueryText }
    const  result = await this.props.relay.environment._network.fetch(getPublicTodosLengthQuery, {})
    return await result.data.viewer.publicTodos.edges.length; 
  }
```

There is value but it's not assigned on my getPublicTodosLength state? I think I don't have to bind here since result returns the data I wanted to assign on getPublicTodosLength state

Comment: the value is there, i want it to assign on getPublicTodosLength but I am failing, cant figure out why @82Tuskers

Comment: What happens if you remove `async` nested within `.setState(...` ? (not an expert with `async` and `await` constructs .. :/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your *state* to be dependent on server data you should use `componentDidMount()`.

> **componentWillMount()** is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before *render()*, therefore **setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.**
>   This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.
>
> **componentDidMount()** is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. **If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request**. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

[From React Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

Answer (score 1):

Why not rather do something like this?

```
...
async componentWillMount() {
  const getPublicTodosLength = this.state.getPublicTodosLength;
  const result = await this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination();
  this.setState({
    getPublicTodosLength: result+getPublicTodosLength,
  });
}
...
```

It's simpler and easier to read. I think the problem with the original code is with using async function inside setState(). In transpiled code there is another wrapper function created and then it probably loose context.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use:

Code snippet:

```
(async ({getPublicTodosLength}, props) => {
      const result =  await this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination();
      console.log("result = ", result);
      return { getPublicTodosLength: result + getPublicTodosLength }
})).then((v)=> this.setState(v));
```

Please let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

i decided to make componentWillMount async and it worked well.

this is the code:

```
componentWillMount = async () => {
    let result =  await this.getPublicTodosLengthForPagination();
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { 
        getPublicTodosLength: result 
      }
    });
  }
```